# Screenshot with Cucumber Groovy

Tags: cucumber, screenshot, katalon-studio

I am working with Cucumber features and Groovy as Step definitions in Katalon Studio. As we have each step in the step definition and wanted to take a screenshot when the step is failed (AShot or whatever). I would like to have the code to take the snap and would like to know do we need this in each step definition file.

I saw this similar question in this forum but does not have a clear answer.

Please note that I know the option in “Take Screenshot when execution failed” in settings.

Can you please provide the sample on this to proceed further?

Answer (score 0):

1st you are planning to run as a test suite of your test pack, you don't need to add any code to capture screenshots, Katalon will automatically do that.

for running as a test case use below example

```
public void catchNotyMessage(){

TestObject noty_warning = WebUI.modifyObjectProperty(findTestObject("DUMMY"), 'css', 'equals', 'div.noty_type_warning', true)
TestObject noty_error = WebUI.modifyObjectProperty(findTestObject("DUMMY"), 'css', 'equals', 'div.noty_type_error', true)

if (WebUI.verifyElementPresent(noty_error, 1, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)){
    this.takeWebElementScreenshot(noty_error)
}
else if (WebUI.verifyElementPresent(noty_warning, 1, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)){
    this.takeWebElementScreenshot(noty_warning)
}
```

}

Comment: this : https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/34621/screenshot-with-katalon-and-chrome-headless-mode

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I will be running it as test suite only. So, in this case, i don't have add my script to the suite. **Continuation to this question, during the execution of cucumber groovy scripts, what else do I need to take care and how I need to proceed further as I am newly starting this cucumber groovy project. It is about exception handling, Sync up time across the scripts. For each cucumber step file whenever the error comes when we run with suite, it will take screen shot, but how it should come out or exit from the script ?**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your `@After` test hook (or [Test Listeners](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/test-listeners-test-hooks.html)):

```
@After
public void TearDown(Scenario scenario) {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
            byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
            scenario.write(scenario.getName());
    }
}
```

You will need some imports:

```
import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory;
```

(Or just pres `Ctrl + Shift + O` to automatically import the missing classes.)